# Laplace's Equation with One Inhomogeneous Boundary Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

While solving Laplace's equation,

$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0,
$$

with Dirichlet boundary conditions

$$\begin{align}
u(x,0)&=f_1(x),\\
u(x,b)&=0,\\
u(0,y)&=0,\\
u(a,y)&=0,
\end{align}$$

and assuming that the solution has the separable form $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, I ran into the case where I have to solve the ODE

$$
Y''(y)=\lambda Y(y),
$$

which has only one homogeneous boundary condition.

My book immediately concludes that its solution is

$$
Y(y)=c_1\sinh\frac{n\pi}a(y-b)\tag{1}
$$

where $\lambda=\left(\frac{n\pi}a\right)^2$ was previously computed.

I cannot understand how $(1)$ was obtained. Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit 1**

If it helps to know, I computed that

$$
X_n(x)=A_n\sin\frac{n\pi}ax,
$$

where $n=1,2,\dots$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your boundary condition is $Y(b) = 0$.   Looking for solutions of the differential equation of the form $u(y) = e^{ry}$, we find $r^2 = \lambda$, so $r = \pm \sqrt{\lambda}$.  Now
the general solution of the differential equation can  be written as $u(y) = c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda} y} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} y}$.  If the boundary condition was $Y(0) = 0$, we would immediately see that $c_1 + c_2 = 0$, so $u(y) = c_1 \left(e^{\sqrt{\lambda} y} - e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} y}\right) = 2 c_1 \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda} y)$.  But note that $v(y) = u(y-b)$ is a solution of the differential equation if $u$ is, and $v(b) = u(0)$.  So we get
$v(y) = 2 c_1 \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda} (y - b))$.  And now absorb the $2$ into the arbitrary 
constant $c_1$ to get the book's $Y(y)$.

Comment: That made perfect sense! I would have never figured it out myself. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- I like to take advantage of *homogeneous boundary conditions*:
  \begin{align}
  &\on{u}\pars{x,y} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{a}_{n}\pars{y}
  \sin\pars{k_{n}x}\,,\qquad k_{n} \equiv n\,{\pi \over a}
  \end{align}
- $\ds{\on{u}\pars{x,y}}$ *must* satisfies the Laplace differential equation:
  $$
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\on{a}_{n}''\pars{y} - k_{n}^{2}\on{a}_{n}\pars{y}}\sin\pars{k_{n}x} = 0
  $$
- Multiply both members by $\ds{2\sin\pars{k_{n}x}/a}$ and integrate over $\ds{x \in \pars{0,a}}$:
  $$
  \on{a}_{n}''\pars{y} - k_{n}^{2}\on{a}_{n}\pars{y} = 0
  $$
  The solutions are linear combinations of $\ds{\expo{\pm k_{n}y}}$. In order to satisfy $\ds{\on{u}\pars{x,b} = 0}$, I choose $\ds{b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}\bracks{b - y}}}$ such that the solution becomes
  $$
  \on{u}\pars{x,y} =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}\bracks{b - y}}
  \sin\pars{k_{n}x}
  $$
- It *must* satisfy the boundary condition
  $\ds{\on{u}\pars{x,0} = \on{f}_{1}\pars{x}}$. Namely,
  $$
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}b}\sin\pars{k_{n}x}
  = \on{f}_{1}\pars{x}
  $$
  Again, multiply both members by $\ds{2\sin\pars{k_{n}x}/a}$ and integrate over $\ds{x \in \pars{0,a}}$:
  \begin{align}
  & b_{n}\sinh\pars{k_{n}b}
  = {2 \over a}\int_{0}^{a}\on{f}_{1}\pars{x}\sin\pars{k_{n}x}
  \,\dd x \equiv \varphi_{n}
  \\ \implies &\
  b_{n} = {\varphi_{n} \over \sinh\pars{k_{n}b}}
  \\[5mm] \implies &\
  \bbx{\on{u}\pars{x,y} =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\varphi_{n}  \over \sinh\pars{k_{n}b}}
  \sinh\pars{k_{n}\bracks{b - y}} 
  \sin\pars{k_{n}x}} \\ &
  \end{align}